# Cannot execute any Mockito test. With JDK17 gives "NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(...) "

Tags: mockito, springmockito

When upgrading my app from Spring Boot 2.2 with JDK 11 to Spring Boot 2.5.5 with JDK 17, Mockito gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
```

In **other posts** the solution is to use the right Mockito-core. I use even a newer one: 4.2.0.

The **other solution** is to remove the Mockito core from the spring-boot-test-starter. Done as well, no solution.

Again **another solution** is to use the newest net.buddy (after excluding in other packages). I did, no solution.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Using mock( ) was **another option**, alas, that gave the same error.

**Working with a @MockBean** resulted gave no solution.

Finally I also ported all tests to a **JUnit 5 version**. Still the same error is given.

This is the simplified class I want to test:

```
@Service
public class ForTestingChild {
    public String getExternalStuff( String input) {
        return "Get that external input";
    }
}
```

The is the simplified class using the previous class:

```
@Service
public class ForTestingThisIsParent {
    private ForTestingChild forTestingChild;
    public ForTestingThisIsParent( ForTestingChild forTestingChild) {
        this.forTestingChild = forTestingChild;
    }
    public String getValueFromChild( String input) {
        return forTestingChild.getExternalStuff( input);
    }
}
```

This is the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ForTestingThisIsParentTest {
    @Mock
    ForTestingChild forTestingChild;

    @InjectMocks
    ForTestingThisIsParent forTestingThisIsParent;

    @Test
    public void testBasic() {
        when( forTestingChild.getExternalStuff( any())).thenReturn( "Simulated external stuff");
        assertEquals( "Simulated external stuff", forTestingThisIsParent.getValueFromChild( "Nonesense stuff"));
    }
}
```

This is the message and the stacktrace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class nl.*****.fortesting.ForTestingChild.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
.... 

Underlying exception : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:39)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:821)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:121)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:65)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1855)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Disabled.initialize(ClassInjector.java:1366)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.inject(ClassInjector.java:1202)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$ForUnsafeInjection.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:458)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Indirect.make(ClassInjector.java:684)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:302)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:70)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:184)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1269)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1257)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:1136)
    ... 53 more
```

The **dependency tree** is:

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.12.5:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.12.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.53:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.53:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.10:compile
|     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.10:compile
|     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.10:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:3.5.5:compile
|     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:3.5.5:compile
|        +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:1.3.4:compile
|        +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
|        \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
|  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile
|  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile
|  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
|  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile
|  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:compile
|  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
|  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.10:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.10:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.5.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.53:compile
|  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.0.Final:compile
|     \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
+- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.12.5:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.5:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.5:compile
|  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.5:compile
+- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.25:compile
+- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.1:compile
+- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.6.0:compile
|  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
|  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
+- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
|  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
+- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
+- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.5.2:compile
+- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.9.3:compile
|  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:2.8.0:compile
|  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.31:compile
|  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.31:compile
|     \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
+- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:jar:4.9.3:compile
|  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.5.31:compile
|     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.5.31:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.5.5:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.5.5:test
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.5:test
|  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
|  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.19.0:test
|  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
|  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
|  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
|  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
|  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.10:test
|  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.2:test
+- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
|  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
|  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
|  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
|  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
|  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
+- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.1.0:test
|  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.24.0:test
|     +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test
|     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.5.5:compile (optional) 
+- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-dep:jar:1.12.3:compile
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.2:compile
|  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:9.2:compile
\- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.9:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an Intelli-J issue!

So, cleaning the Intelli-J dependency spaghetti up solved it!

1. File > Invalidate cache ... and restart. Helped a bit.
2. Closing the Intelli-J project. Then removed manually the ".idea" folder and any *.iml file.

Yes, I did option 1 previously. Especially doing action 2 solved it within a minute.